# How to make an multidimensional array from this query

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Query:

```
SELECT
    c.id campaign_id,
    c.campaign_title,
    c.start_date campaign_start_date,
    c.end_date campaign_end_date,
    cat.id category_id,
    cat.category_title,
    n.id nominee_id,
    n.title nominee_title,
    u.id voter_id,
    u.fullname voter_name
FROM
    campaign c
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.campaign_id = c.id
LEFT JOIN category_nominees cn ON cn.category_id = cat.id
LEFT JOIN nominees n ON n.id = cn.nominee_id
LEFT JOIN category_votes cv ON cv.campaign_id = c.id
AND cv.category_id = cat.id
AND cv.nominee_id = n.id
LEFT JOIN users u on u.id = cv.user_id
WHERE
    c.active = 1
ORDER BY
    u.fullname,
    c.campaign_title,
    cat.category_order,
    cat.category_title,
    cn.nominee_order,
    n.title
```

And with that query I would use PHP to logically store all of that data in nested associative arrays, and then whenever you loop through data or need to reference data you would refer to the array pointer rather than doing new queries each time.

For example:
$campaigns[$campaign_id]['categories'][$category_id]['nominees'][$nominee_id]['title'] is one possible approach.

I've tried

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    if (!isset($rows[$row['campaign_id']])) {
        $rows[$row['campaign_id']] = array(
            'campaign_id' => $row['campaign_id'],
            'category_id' => array()
        );
    }

    array_push ($rows[$row['campaign_id']]['category_id'],array(
        'category_id' => $row['category_title'],
        'nominees_id' => $row['nominee_id']
    ));

}
```

I can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to add the php code that you have tried: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
$campaigns = array(); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $campaign_id = $row['campaign_id'];
    $category_id = $row['category_id'];
    $nominee_id = $row['nominee_id'];
    $campaigns[$campaign_id]['categories'][$category_id]['nominees'][$nominee_id]['title']
= $row; }
```